# Die and coin variance of random variable question.

Tags: random-variables, variance

Die and coin. Roll a die and flip a coin. Let $Y$ be the value
of the die. Let $Z = 1$ if the coin shows a head, and $Z = 0$ otherwise. Let
$X = Y + Z$. Find the variance of $X$.

My work:

$E(Y) = 1 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} + 2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} +  3 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} +  4 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} +  5 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} + 6 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} = \cfrac{7}{2}$

$E(Z) = 0 \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} + 1 \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} = \cfrac{1}{2}$

So $E(X) = E(Y + Z) = E(Y) + E(Z) = \cfrac{7}{2} + \cfrac{1}{2} = 4$

$E(Y^2) = 1^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} + 2^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} +  3^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} +  4^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} +  5^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} + 6^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{6} = \cfrac{91}{6}$

$E(Z^2) = 0^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} + 1^2 \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} = \cfrac{1}{2}$

so $E(X^2) = E(Y^2 + Z^2) = E(Y^2) + E(Z^2) = \cfrac{91}{6} + \cfrac{1}{2} = \cfrac{47}{3}$

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 = \cfrac{47}{3} - 4^2 = -\cfrac{1}{3}???$

Where did I go wrong, variance can't be negative so clearly my work is wrong, but I have no idea where I went wrong? Can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y\perp\!\!\!\!\!\!\perp Z$ thus $V(X)=V(Y)+V(Z)$

---

Your error is this

$$E(X^2)=E[(Y+Z)^2] \ne E(Y^2)+E(Z^2)$$

Comment: Sorry what does that symbol between Y and Z mean? I'm not too familiar with that symbol.

Comment: @BillBillwater $X$ is independent from $Y$

Comment: Ah Okay, I see thank you, I see my error now. Ill accept your answer when I can

Answer (score 0):

$E(X^2)\ne E(Y^2+Z^2)$

$E(X^2)=E(Y^2+Z^2+2YZ)=E(Y^2)+E(Z^2)+2E(YZ)=\dfrac{91}{6}+\dfrac{1}{2}+2\cdot\dfrac{7}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{47}{3}+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{97}{6}$

$V(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=\dfrac{97}{6}-16=\dfrac{97-96}{6}=\dfrac{1}{6}$

An alternate way:

Since X and Y are independent events covariance term vanishes therefor
$V(X)=V(Y)+V(Z)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2+E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2$

Comment: $E(X^2)=E(Y^2+Z^2+2YZ)=E(Y^2)+E(Z^2)+2E(YZ)=\dfrac{91}{6}+\dfrac{1}{\color{blue}2}+2\cdot\dfrac{7}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}$?

Comment: $X^2=(Y+Z)^2=(Y^2+Z^2+2YZ)$ and $E(Y^2)=\frac{91}{6},E(Z^2)=\frac{1}{2},E(Y)=\frac{1}{2},E(Z)=\frac{1}{2}$ What is your question I didnt get it ?

Comment: Did you mean to type $\frac 1 4$ on the second line of equations in your answer? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Oh yes thanks for pointing that out.